# Angular on Meteor with CoffeeScript/Jade

Tags: angularjs, meteor, coffeescript, meteor-blaze, angular-meteor

I feel like I'm so close, but I get hung up on why this setup isn't working for me. https://github.com/jaruesink/first_meteor

Thanks for anyone who can help out with this, I'm just trying to learn and have fun with a new project.

scripts/_main.coffee

```
@App = angular.module('App', [
'angular-meteor'
'ngMaterial'
'ui.router'
])

@App.config [
    '$interpolateProvider'
    ($interpolateProvider) ->
        $interpolateProvider
            .startSymbol '[['
            .endSymbol   ']]'
]
```

scripts/router.coffee

```
@App.config [
    '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider'
    ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) ->
        $locationProvider.html5Mode true
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/home'
        $stateProvider.state('home'
            url: '/home'
            templateUrl: UiRouter.template 'home'
        )
]
```

index.jade

```
head
    title App
    base(href="/")
body(ng-app="App")
    div.container
        h1 If 2 + 5 = [[2+5]], then I'm working :-)
        p but why isn't the router below showing up?
        div(ui-view)
```

views/home/home.jade

```
template(name='home')
section#home
    div.container
        h1 hello world, 1 + 2 = [[1+2]]
```

but here is what happens (the highlighted ui-view repeats the header code with all of the scripts again too)

[image: I get duplicate code where one works and the other doesn't]

[image]

Comment: also for anyone interested these are the packages I have installed so far:

angular:angular-material 0.10.1*  |  

angularui:angular-ui-router 0.2.15 | 

autopublish 1.0.3* | 

bootstrap 1.0.1 | 

insecure 1.0.3* | 

less 1.0.14* | 

meteor-platform 1.2.2* | 

meteorhacks:kadira 2.23.0* | 

mquandalle:jade 0.4.3* | 

ndxbxrme:ng-coffeescript 1.2.2 | 

urigo:angular 0.9.3* | 

urigo:angular-ui-router 0.7.0

Comment: no polemic here but why would you want to use Angular with Meteor? I've done Angular for a while and switched to Meteor: it has all you want and need and more, without the overhead. Just go Meteor and forget Angular; IMO mixing the 2 is just making your life harder for no reason.

Comment: haha @MrE you're probably right for the most part, however I still think angular does some things well that meteor doesn't have. and I'm following angular material very closely and really like how easy they're making it to build up an full app. so that's the main reason

Comment: I'd love to hear some particular examples of what Angular does well that Meteor doesn't.

Comment: http://joshowens.me/meteor-and-angular-a-match-made-in-heaven/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your file router.coffee, On the templateUrl attribute you just need to mention the name of template like below:

```
@App.config [
    '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider'
    ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) ->
        $locationProvider.html5Mode true
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/home'
        $stateProvider.state('home'
            url: '/home'
            templateUrl: 'home'
        )
]
```

Your application will work fine

[image: Test of App]

Comment: that makes me mad haha, thank you so much. I figured it was something simple like that, but the documentation I saw had that other line. anyway much appreciated!!!